# Display Django model data to table in HTML

Tags: django, html-table

I have two Django models that record time. **Model one records time during the morning** and **Model two records time during the evening**. I want to present both of these times along with the difference between the times within an HTML table but am confused about how to do it. I am new to Django and would really appreciate some advice.

This is what I have so far:

**models.py:**

```
class Alltime(models.Model):
    id= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    mtime = models.DateTimeField()
    etime = models.DateTimeField()
```

**views.py:**

```
def panel(request):
    time_data = User.objects.filter(pk__gt=1) #I need all data except for the default Super User account
    get_time = Alltime.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'users/interface.html', {'data': time_data, "get_time": get_time})
```

**panel.html:**

```
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Morning timeE</th> 
    <th>Evening time</th>
    <th>Difference in hours</th>
</tr>
    {% for data in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{data.username}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if get_time %}
        {% for m in get_time %}
            <td>{{m.mtime}}</td>
            <td>{{m.etime}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <td> Not available </td>
    {% endif %}
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

How can I get the difference between the times and place them within the HTML table?

Comment: Each morning and evening object seem to be related? Why not combine them into 1 model?

Comment: @Ive done as requested but how can you calculate the time difference between the two dates and display it in the HTML table?

Comment: You can add a property to the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, then you can/need to structure your data differently. An easy way is to prepare the data in your view:

def panel(request):
    time_data = User.objects.filter(pk__gt=1) 
    time_table=[]
    for user in time_data:

```
    morning_time = Morning.objects.filter(user=user)
    evening_time = Evening.objects.filter(user=user)
    diff = morning_time - evening_time 
    time_table.append((user.name, morning_time, evening_time, diff))
return render(request, 'users/interface.html', {'data': time_table})
```

And in the template:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Morning timeE</th> 
    <th>Evening time</th>
    <th>Difference in hours</th>
</tr>
    {% for line in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{line.0}}</td>
    <td>{{line.1}}</td>
    <td>{{line.2}}</td>
    <td>{{line.3}}</td>

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

You need to add the handling of not existing data in the view code.

Some remarks:
The whole thing does not really make sense to me. I guess you will need to filter for dates too. But you should get the idea from this. And why is it in a form?

Comment: I am actually new to Django so am exploring options here. Nevertheless, I will get back to you on this. Thank you so much for replying

Comment: Where do you close the for loop here?

Comment: Sorry, added this in the answer.

Comment: is it possible to add the time difference to the Evening model?

Comment: Yes you can, use a duration field then: duration = models.DurationField()

Comment: I know it's a bit too much to ask but can you please take a look at this question and help me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540888/how-to-display-django-model-data-in-html-table

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property to the `Alltime` model that returns the difference between the morning and evening time

```
@property
def diff(self):
    return self.etime - self.mtime
```

Then in your template you can use this property

```
    {% for m in get_time %}
        <td>{{m.mtime}}</td>
        <td>{{m.etime}}</td>

        <td>{{m.diff}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: May I know what the @property method does here?

Comment: @danny_boy it turns the method into a read-only descriptor https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/descriptor.html - You can access it just like an attribute of any instance of the class `obj.diff` but you cannot assign to it

Comment: Do I place that property within my models.py or views.py?

Comment: In the definition of the model, just like you would any other method